# Nasm - weird results when multiplying 2 values

Tags: assembly, x86, multiplication, cpu-registers, twos-complement

Edit: I was using [this](https://www.calculator.net/hex-calculator.html) calculator to check the results but it seems like that the calculator itself was calculating wrong values which led to this question.

When using the `mul` instruction I noticed that multiplying 2 high numbers results in a wrong value. Examples:

```
mov eax, 0ffffffffh
mov ebx, 0ffffffffh
mul ebx
; eax:00000001 I expected eax to be 0
; edx:FFFFFFFE

mov eax, 0ffffff00h
mov ebx, 0ffffffffh
mul ebx
; eax:00000100 I expected eax also to be 0
; edx:FFFFFEFF
```

I know that `-1 * -1` is `1` and `ffffffffh` is minus one. But multiplying these two numbers in an unsigned multiplication doesn't result in `1`, or does it? Same goes for the other example.

Also when using the `imul` instruction I get strange numbers too but I think it is because of the signed multiplication:

```
mov eax, 0fffffff0h
mov ebx, 5
imul ebx
; eax:FFFFFFB0
; edx:FFFFFFFF ; I expected edx to be 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your results are normal, your expectations are wrong.  IDK where your wrong expectations came from, but the 64-bit result of 32-bit [`mul`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mul) goes in EDX:EAX.

Turns out it was from an online calculator that presumably used Javascript number, i.e. `double`-precision floating point with a 53-bit mantissa, which will round `0xfffffffe00000001` to the nearest representable double, i.e. `0xfffffffe00000000`.

And for the signed case, you were just using the calculator totally wrong, expecting it to interpret your inputs as 32-bit 2's complement.

---

The low half of a multiply result doesn't depend on whether you interpret the inputs as signed or not, so yes as a shortcut we can use `-1 * -1 = 1` to get the low half here.  (That's why Intel only bothered to add efficient non-widening forms for `imul`, e.g. `imul eax, edx, -1`).

If we simply try it in an extended-precision calculator like [`calc`](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/calc/index.html) (packaged in Ubuntu as `apcalc`, and in Arch as `calc`):

```
; base2(16)    // ask for hex output as well as decimal

; 0x0ffffffff ^ 2
        18446744065119617025 /* 0xfffffffe00000001 */

; 0x0ffffff00 * 0x0ffffffff
        18446742969902956800 /* 0xfffffeff00000100 */
```

So this confirms the CPU's results.  Remember that and odd number times an odd number is an odd number, so your EAX=0 guess for `0xffffffff * 0xffffffff` can also be ruled out that way.

---

For signed it's a little trickier to do with an arbitrary-precision calculator:

```
; (0xfffffff0 - 2^32) * 5
        -80 /* -0x50 */
; . + 2^64                  // get the 64-bit 2's complement bit-pattern for that negative number
        18446744073709551536 /* 0xffffffffffffffb0 */
```

That small unsigned number of course splits up into `0xffffffff`  and `0xffffffb0`, with EDX just being all-ones, same as the upper bits of EAX, because that's how sign-extension works.

Comment: I used an [hex calculator](https://www.calculator.net/hex-calculator.html) I found on the Internet that told me that `FFFFFF0*5 = 4FFFFFFB0` which is why I thought that `edx` should be 4 instead of `FFFFFFFF`. Also the result of `FFFFFFFF*FFFFFFFF` was `FFFFFFFE00000000` in this calculator. Is that an implementation error or how can that be explained?

Comment: @MenNotAtWork: `4FFFFFB0` is the correct result for unsigned multiplication of `0x0FFFFFF0 * 5` which is what you asked the online calculator to do.  It doesn't treat the input as 32-bit 2's complement.  (Also, you left out one `F` in your comment just now).  Notice how I used `0xfffffff0 - 2^32` to get the negative number that `0xfffffff0` represents as a 2's complement bit-pattern.

Comment: @MenNotAtWork: That online calculator's result for `FFFFFFFF` squared is wrong.  Perhaps its using double-precision floating point instead of extended-precision integers?  If it's just written naively in JavaScript that's probably what happened; Javascript numbers are IEEE `double` so you can get rounding error.  Your question would make a lot more sense (and be more answerable) if you included the source of your wrong results.  I was really tempted to downvote it because there's no justification for why you'd expect those wrong results other than what you put in your comment just now.